# Getting blank screenshot using html2canvas in Angular

Tags: angular, screenshot, html2canvas, capture

In the component file I have:

```js
const video = <HTMLVideoElement> this.videoElement.nativeElement;
html2canvas(video, { 
  logging: true,
  allowTaint: false,
  useCORS: true,
})
.then((canvas) => {
  const file = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  this.imageFile = this.dataURLtoFile(file, 'image.png');
});
```

Comment: Share code of your html

Comment: I’m not sure I would expect a Video to show on a “screenshot” taken in this manner.

Comment: <video fxFlex="100" #videoElement class="video" controls>
          <source [src]="url" autoplay type="video/mp4" />
</video>    //this is the code from where screenshot is taken

Comment: <button>
          Take Screenshot</button>        <img [src]="src">

Comment: @navnath this is complete code